# setStreamVolume() doesn't seem to work after turning Do not Disturb off

Tags: android, audio, volume, android-audiomanager, notificationmanager

So I'm writing an app whose soul purpose is to turn the phone on full volume ringer mode, even from do not disturb mode. My app has notification filter change permission, so I am able to pull it out of DnD mode. Sweet. I've learned via logging that when I turn off DnD mode programmatically, ringer mode is set to normal, and ring volume is set to 1. But when I use setStreamVolume to max volume, it doesn't change the volume. Even more notably, I also can't manually turn the volume up via the volume rocker. The only way I have figured out how to increase the ring volume immediately after coming out of DnD mode is by using the volume slider on the screen. Another point is that when the ring volume is set to any value above 1 and then I test my app, setStreamVolume works. Am I missing something here? Here's some code.

Here is my receiver that detects when DnD mode is changed.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction() !=null && intent.getAction().equals(NotificationManager.ACTION_INTERRUPTION_FILTER_CHANGED)) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (mNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALARMS) {
            Log.i("NotificationFilter", "filter alarms");
        } else if (mNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL) {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            Log.i("NotificationFilter", "filter all, " + am.getStreamVolume(STREAM_RING));
            int vol = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, vol, FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        }
    }
}
```